# Recycler view inside a Custom Compound view

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I need to create a `RecyclerView` inside a custom view. Following my code:

```
public class CitySinglePageGridView extends LinearLayout {
    Context context ;
    View mView ;
    RecyclerView recyclerView ;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager  layoutManager ;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;



public CitySinglePageGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context ;


    LayoutInflater inflater;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.module_city_single_page_gridview,this,true);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) mView.findViewById(R.id.cardList);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


    layoutManager =  new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter = new CityCardviewAdapter();

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
}
```

The problem is when I run the application nothing shows in the custom view, but when I'm using this RecyclerView  in a `Fragment` or `Activity` everything works fine.

Following my custom adapter:

```
public class CityCardviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CityCardviewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_card_item_city, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 5;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    protected TextView title;
    protected TextView desc ;
    protected TextView distance ;
    protected TextView likeCount ;
    protected ImageView thumbnail ;
    protected ImageView like ;
    protected ImageView Distance ;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title =  (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        distance = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.distance);
        likeCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.likeCount);
        thumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        like = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.like);
        Distance = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nav);
        }
    }
}
```

I set `getItemCount` to 5 to test the application.

Comment: did you try hierarchyviewer?

Comment: @pskink i checked hierarchyviewer and it seems that the view is present !

Comment: what size does it have?

Comment: @pskink really thank you , i found the problem , this problem is because that custom view is inside a scrollview :)